# check if session exist and has specific value

Tags: php, session

i'm trying to check if a session exist and has a specific value (2) to show a part of the website and if not it should return you to a other page.

So far i got this:

```
$_SESSION["deel"] = "2";  //set session deel to 2
$result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
$result["error"] = false;
$result["html"] = "<h3>Session information:";
$result["html"] .= "<a href='/shop/?,69'>$_SESSION[class2C]</a>";
$result["html"] .= "</h3>";
```

after that we go to a other page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['deel']) || $_SESSION['deel'] == '2')
{ show the shit }
else 
{ redirect }
```

However, it doesn't do anything and just shows me "the shit"
what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about a session_start() before you use session?

Comment: this is only a part of the total script and yes the session gets started. in above scripts and this file itself.

Comment: Then why you check if the session['deel'] is NOT set OR it's equal to 2? So if it's not set you show sh*t, but if it is set and equal's to 2 you also show sh*t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['deel']) || $_SESSION['deel'] == '2')
    ^                         ^^
```

Means if the session is not set or if it is set then the value is 2, This will be true even if there is no session. You should do:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['deel']) && $_SESSION['deel'] == 2)
```

This can also be derived from your own statement

> i'm trying to check if a session exist and has a specific value (2)

```
                      ^       ^          ^
 if (isset($_SESSION['deel']) &&  $_SESSION['deel'] == 2)
```

Comment: damnit, im still confusing the !isset and isset.. didnt know what the || did in this case i thought i was something similar to &&

Comment: Oops then you must go through this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: `!` before something means `NOT` of that. `&&` means `AND`, `||` means `OR`. That post i mentioned explains it all clearly

Comment: Thanks again dude. Didn't check it out yet but i do now and i found it very usefull :)